# Replace letters in string with the next letter, and capitalize vowels in the changed string

Tags: javascript

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var index = alphabet.indexOf(str[i])
        if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i])) {
            str = str.replace(str[i], alphabet.charAt(index + 1));
        }
        if (/[aeiou]/.test(str[i])) {
            str = str.replace(str[i], alphabet.charAt(index + 26));
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

When I call `LetterChanges("hello")`, it returns `'Ifmmp'` which is correct, but when `"sent"` is passed it returns `'ufOt'` instead of `'tfOu'`. Why is that?

Comment: Because the first time through the loop it replaces `s` with `t`, so `str` is `tent`. On the fourth iteration, it replaces `t` with `u`, and that replaces the first `t`, not the last one. You should accumulate the characters one at a time in a new variable, not replace characters in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace()` replaces the first occurrence of the match in the string with the replacement. `LetterChanges("sent")` does the following:

- `i` = 0 : `str.replace("s", "t")`, now `str` = "tent"
- `i` = 1 : `str.replace("e", "f")`, now `str` = "tfnt"
- `i` = 2 : `str.replace("n", "o")`, now `str` = "tfot", then
          `str.replace("o", "O")`, now `str` = "tfOt"
- `i` = 3 : `str.replace("t", "u")`, now `str` = "ufOt"
- `return str`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues. The main one is that you could inadvertently change the same letter several times.

Let's see what happens to the `s` in `sent`. You first change it to `t`. However, when it comes to changing the final letter, which is also `t`, you change the first letter *again*, this time from `t` to `u`.

Another, smaller, issue is the handling of the letter `z`.

Finally, your indexing in the second `if` is off by one: `d` becomes `D` and not `E`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to avoid that:

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c){
        return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)+1);
    }).replace(/[aeiou]/g, function(c){
        return c.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

But there is still a bug: `LetterChanges('Zebra')` will return `'[fcsb'`. I assume that is not your intention. You will have to handle the shift.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   var result = '';
  var temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        var index = alphabet.indexOf(str[i])

        if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i])) {
            //str = str.replace(str[i], alphabet.charAt(index + 1));
          temp= alphabet.charAt(index + 1);
          index = index+1;
        }
      else if(str[i] == ' '){
      temp = ' ';
      }
        if (/[aeiou]/.test(temp)) {
            temp = alphabet.charAt(index + 26);
        }

      result += temp;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'bcd12';

str = str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(char) { //call replace method
  char = String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0)+1);//increment ascii code of char variable by 1 .FromCharCode() method will convert Unicode values into character 
  if (char=='{' || char=='[') char = 'a'; //if char values goes to "[" or"{" on incrementing by one as "[ ascii value is 91 just after Z" and "{ ascii value is 123 just after "z" so assign "a" to char variable..  
  if (/[aeiuo]/.test(char)) char = char.toUpperCase();//convert vowels to uppercase
  return char;
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some explanation to your code block. This is a suggestion to improve this and future answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code sample. There is no bug in it. Not pretty straight forward but Works like a charm. Cheers!

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 
  var temp = str;
  var tempArr = temp.split("");//Split the input to convert it to an Array
  tempArr.forEach(changeLetter);/*Not many use this but this is the referred way of using loops in javascript*/
  str = tempArr.join("");

  // code goes here  
  return str; 

}

function changeLetter(ele,index,arr) {
  var lowerLetters ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza";
  var upperLetters ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA";
  var lowLetterArr = lowerLetters.split("");
  var upLetterArr = upperLetters.split("");
  var i =0; 

  for(i;i<lowLetterArr.length;i++){
    if(arr[index] === lowLetterArr[i]){
      arr[index] = lowLetterArr[i+1];
      arr[index]=arr[index].replace(/[aeiou]/g,arr[index].toUpperCase());
      return false;
    }
    if(arr[index] === upLetterArr[i]){
      arr[index] = upLetterArr[i+1];
      arr[index]=arr[index].replace(/[aeiou]/g,arr[index].toUpperCase());
      return false;
    }
  }

}

// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
LetterChanges(readline());
```